# Embed Youtube on Three.js Scene ( CSS3DRenderer, WebGLRenderer )

Tags: three.js

before asking a question let you know that I already tried some ways.

[I-asked-before-this-question-but-no-help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60521950/use-css3drenderer-with-webglrenderer-on-three-js-embedding-youtube-in-three-js)

[Mixing HTML Pages Inside Your WebGL](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/)

[stemkoski-css3d.html](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/)

http://run.plnkr.co/preview/ck7d1p1t4000a3b5uxqhm17vk/

and more..

I'm trying to embedding youtube on my three.js scene.

But I have issues that I cannot embed it.

Thre problem for now, Youtube is not appear.

On chrome debugger, I can see css3dobject's frame, but there is nothing on Three.js scene.

[image: iframe-doesn't-show-up]

Here's my code.

```
...
//create css3dobject
    let element = document.createElement('iframe');
    element.src = [ 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/jO2viLEW-1A', '?rel=0' ].join( '' );  //test url
    element.style.width = '200px';
    element.style.height = '150px';
    let cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
    cssObject.position.set(325, 50, 25);// = child.position;
    cssObject.rotation.set( 0, 0, 0);// = child.rotation;
    cssObject.scale.x = 100;
    cssObject.scale.y = 100;
    cssObject.scale.z = 100;

    cssScene.add(cssObject);

//setting renderer..
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true} );    
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    renderer.autoClear = false;
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    cssRenderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer({alpha: true});
    cssRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    cssRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    cssRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;

    document.body.appendChild(cssRenderer.domElement);

    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    renderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
    renderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 1;

    cssRenderer.domElement.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
...

function render(){
    cssRenderer.render(cssScene, camera);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias: true, alpha:true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true} );
renderer.domElement.style.background = ''
renderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 0;

 cssRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 1;
```

You're spelling .zIndex wrong. it's case sensitive. Also included some other tricks you may need, going forward, if you plan to to anything more fancy.

Comment: When I post this question, there was wrong typing for `zIndex`. and I give some attributes you mentioned to renderer, but still same.